# Why does the screen go dead until I press escape every time I boot up?

Tags: boot, grub2, login-screen

I have Ubuntu Studio 14.04, it is the only operating system on my machine.
Every time I boot up, the BIOS loads, and then the screen goes dead and will stay that way unless I press ESC, in which case the prompt to enter my password for disk encryption appears, after which everything proceeds normally. It's always done this since I installed it a few months ago. But when I realized I only had to press ESC, I decided to ignore this (minor) matter. But sometimes the screen stays dead after waking it up from being suspended, and then nothing I do with the keyboard helps - which maybe is a separate question, or maybe is related.

What is this about and how can i address it?

Update: I installed a proprietary driver from Nvidia, based on Azendale's input that the graphics driver may be the issue. The problem has now been replaced by a different problem. My USB keyboard doesn't work until after the password for the disk encryption program is entered, so I keep a standard keyboard connected just to enter it. It still seems, as Zacharee1 mentioned in the comments, that the disk encryption software is the cause of both issues, and I need to remove it.

In case it wasn't clear and it in some way matters, *only* the ESC key would get the screen working before.

Comment: Your disk encryption is BIOS run right? It might just be interfering with Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a service that came with Studio. When i installed Studio i was asked if i wanted to use it. I'm sorry i don't remember the name of the program, not sure where to find it.

Comment: Then you might want to disable it. It's obviously causing problems. If you can find what the package is called, disable the encryption and then run `sudo apt-get remove --purge [package name]` before reinstalling it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think it's name is shown when i'm prompted to enter the password. I'll reboot to see if i can find it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 turns out the disk encryption is part of Ubuntu itself,  i enabled it on install and now only a reinstall could remove it.  See http://askubuntu.com/q/628006/364597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a disk encryption issue, other than that the disk encryption waits for a key to be typed. Instead, it sounds like a Plymouth (graphical bootsplash part of the system) & Graphics driver bug. Hitting ESC gets you out of the graphical boot screen to the text only one that works better with the graphics driver in use. You may want to see if you can find anything related to your brand & model of graphics card and Plymouth not showing up correctly.

Comment: Installing a graphics driver from Nvidia sort of fixed the issue. Now I have to enter the password the encryption software requires with a keyboard connected to the standard keyboard port, because my usb keyboard isn't recognized until after that is done. :P That wasn't the case before. So I still think I have to get around to uninstalling that disk encryption software.