# How can I get rid of Ubuntu disk encryption bugs?

Tags: boot, encryption

When I first installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04 a few months ago, I chose the option for the disk to be encrypted. I have had two issues since then that I believe have to do with it.

For a while every time I booted up, my screen went dead after BIOS finished loading, and the only way to get out of that was to press Escape - no other key, only ESC worked. Then boot-up proceeded just fine.

After replacing my graphics driver with one from Nvidia that problem was replaced with the USB keyboard not being loaded when I have to enter the password for the encryption program. Now I keep a standard keyboard connected just to enter that, and afterwards switch to the wireless USB keyboard.

I would prefer to keep the disk encryption - as much because I would rather not have to reinstall Ubuntu as because I find it reassuring. Is there anything I can do about the keyboard problem?

I included a description of the previous dead-screen problem in case that gives a clue what is going on. I asked about that [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/609794/364597) at Ask.SE at the time and got help for it.

Edit: My machine has only the Ubuntu OS on it, nothing else. It does have two old drives on it that I have never been able to mount and just left... could that be a factor?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue ([bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1238194)), the kernel driver  module is not loaded as it is on the encripted drive, so you need to add it to the appropriate file.

Boot Ubuntu using the ps/2 keyboard

Open a terminal window, and run

```
sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Add `ohci_pci` on a new line at the bottom of the file.

If you’re using an Apple keyboard, you’ll probably need to add `hid_apple` and `mac_hid`.

If you’re using a Microsoft keyboard, you’ll need to add `hid_microsoft`

If you’re using a Logitech keyboard `hid_logitech` and `hid_logitech_dj`

Once you’ve added all of the required modules, press ctrl+X to save and close the file.

Back in the terminal window, run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now reboot and your wireless keyboard should work.

Comment: I didn't get it at first - you have to add the    ohci_pci    etc and then press ctrl X, which is to exit. When you do that it asks you if you want to save. Then it puts you into a screen where you can save under a different name, but if you press enter it takes you out of that, and just saves under the same name.

Comment: OK, thanks, added that to the answer, did it work ?

Comment: No, not so far. I had to do a hard shutdown because anything else kept giving me a 'Failed to run action' Error, saying the session manager must be idle.  I rebooted and again had to use the PS/2 keyboard, and it is still giving me the error. But it did update when i finished the instructions before.  I included hid_microsoft, hid_logitech, and hid_logitech_dj. I have a logitech keyboard, but thought it wouldn't matter if i added on an extra module because it would detect what was connected, and that way the module is there if needed. Did that screw it up?

Comment: So, because i didn't want to keep doing hard shut-downs on my machine, and because other odd behaviors had appeared, i reinstalled Ubuntu. This time i chose the stable edition, 14.04, instead of Studio which is badly supported and rough around the edges, and didn't encrypt the disk. And i will try to pay more attention when using the terminal from now on. :/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the bios does not know what is to boot into... Try loading bios and make sure the drive Ubuntu is on is set as the default  boot device.

Comment: There is no other partition on the drive, it is a pure Ubuntu machine.  Maybe i should edit that into the question.